# Change of research area for Postdoc

Tags: mathematics, advisor, postdocs, changing-fields, research-topic

I did a Ph.D. in the area of engineering mathematics. The thesis used some of the concepts from Mathematics, such as basic probability and statistics (Bachelor/Master level), calculus (Bachelor/Master level), optimization (Bachelor/Master level), etc. Mostly, the works applied the existing mathematical tools to some physical problems instead of developing methods.
However, it was possible to publish some of the works in good applied mathematics/mechanics journals.

All my undergraduate and graduate degrees were obtained from the mathematics department of a reputed institution in India. Being a student of Mathematics background, I now want to learn and work in the area of applied numerical analysis/scientific computation.

I am currently working as a postdoc researcher in a reputed university in the USA, but that also in the area of engineering mathematics. Is it possible to get a postdoc opportunity in the area of applied numerical analysis/scientific computation or other related areas where mathematical techniques are developed rather than using it? In that case, how to convince the supervisor that I am capable of learning the research topic and work on it when I have no such publication record yet? Please give your suggestion on how to proceed.

Comment: That's exactly how doing a postdoc works.